# How to enable interact on UI while method is still running in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, synchronization

I have a logic on client side which will take around 10 seconds or more time to evaluate, but in the moment of waiting the screen it will change to a new screen where i wish the screen is enable for user to interact while waiting.

Now the problem is although the screen is changed, but it is unable to interact on it unless the method is completed.

I try to search on internet, but i realise GWT is not support synchronized. What is the alternative way to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Why do not put your task which lasts 10 seconds on the server and then react on the asynchronous callback?

Comment: i am looking for a solution for less dependance on server. anyways thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

GWT creates JavaScript - you can do everything with GWT that you can do with JavaScript. JavaScript does not allow multithreading - you will have to use [Web Workers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx).